# use of “induce” in a sentence

Tags: sentence-construction

Is use of "induce" in the following sentences correct grammatically and conceptually? could you please suggest some word to replace "induce" and "strongly"?

> It indicates that the stall condition of the turbine is induced strongly
>   by the flow around the tip which is due to the tip leakage flow and
>   also separation at blade tip.

Answer (score 2):

It is a formal usage of the term [induce](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/induce) meaning:

> - to bring about, produce, or cause:
>     *That medicine will induce sleep*.

Dictionary.com

- as stated above, ***cause or produce*** can be used alternatively to induce.
- you can replace strongly with ***powerfully***.

Answer (score 1):

> In fluid dynamics, a stall is a reduction in the lift coefficient
>   generated by a foil as angle of attack. A stall is a condition in
>   aerodynamics and aviation wherein the angle of attack increases beyond
>   a certain point such that lift begins to decrease.

In this sentence:

> It indicates that the stall condition of the turbine is induced
>   strongly by the flow around the tip which is due to the tip leakage
>   flow and also separation at blade tip.

*'Induced'* here can either mean **"to produce/cause"** or **"to stimulate"** and *'strongly'* would probably mean **"numerously"**